# Changing the threshold for an appender in Grails

Tags: grails, logging, configuration

In Grails the logging is setup in the Config.groovy file. Those properties can be overridden via an external properties file (as defined by grails.config.locations).

My question is this: How can I change the threshold of a particular appender via the properties file? What is the property name of this?

I've tried variations of:

```
log4j.appenders.rollingApplicationAppender.threshold=org.apache.log4j.Level.DEBUG
```

But that has not been successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of log4j and logging. What you are asking to do can't be done and I will explain why.

Logging is based on two concepts. `Loggers` and `Appenders`. Loggers, receive messages, inspect those messages and determine based on their configuration if the message should be sent along to the appender. `Threshold` is a property of the `logger`. Thus, when a message arrives it's first evaluated by the `logger` before being sent to the `appender`. The `appender` in turn understands how to write the message to the appropriate output and has no understanding of `threshold`.

Hope this helps you further understand how logging works and leads you towards accomplishing what you are looking to do.

**Update**

As pointed out in the comments `appenders` do have the ability to also apply their own `threshold` after a message has been identified by a `logger` as valid. This allows them the ability to discard a message (common use is to discard TRACE in production for console output). With this in mind, your example in the question is doing just that. setting the `threshold` for the `appender` but you aren't seeing any output to the `appender` because your `logger` is first filtering the messages.

Comment: That's what I was thinking also, but the base class for pretty much every `Appender` is `org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton` and it has a method `public void setThreshold(Priority threshold)` (`Level` extends `Priority`) which for some reason isn't in the interface.

Comment: Ah, excellent catch Burt. It does appear that the appender has a thereshold setting itself for an additional level of filtering. E.g. once a message has passed the logger threshold the appender has a chance to also evaluate the level before appending. I will update the answer to indicate this.